# C++, modify values in double array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have the following code

```
double * p;
p = new double[SIZE];

// function that is called multiple times
void doSomething(int id, double time) {
   if (id > 0) {
     p[id - 1] += time;
   }
   // different version
   if (id > 0) {
     *(p(id - 1)) += time;
   }
}
```

Both cases show really big negative numbers, what is the problem? However, `p[id - 1] = time` or `*(p(id - 1)) = time` show the right values.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default value. In this case that means changing `double * p; p = new double[SIZE]`; to `double * p = new double[SIZE];`.

Comment: you should use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: @PeteBecker yes you're right, I had to initialize the values of the array. However, I couldn't do it by changing the declaration, because it was in header which I couldn't change, so I populated the array with 0s with a for-loop.

Comment: What are the "right" values? Since the right value apparently occurs with a simple assignment, why would you think adding to the correct value would also produce a correct value?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `p`'s elements are not 0 by default and have garbage value in them.

`new double[SIZE]` makes an array of doubles and default-initializes each element.
Default-initialization for fundamental types does not do anything.
`new double[SIZE]()` makes an array of doubles and value-initializes each element.
Value-initialization for fundamental types does zero-initialization.

So basically by using the second version you can initialize all array elements to 0. Then you can += them.

Answer (score 1):

1. The 2nd option (`*(p(id - 1)) += time;`) should not compile. It doesn't on MSVC.
2. Your code attempts to add `time` to elements in the `p` array. But even though `p = new double[SIZE];` is handling the memory allocation , it does not handle initialization. Allocated memory in C/C++ is not initiazlied by default. You simply get random values that were in this memory area. Therefore you attempt to add a value to uninitizlied mempory that can contain anything. You wrote that `p[id - 1] = time` gives you the proper value. This is because this assignment does not rely on automatic initialization.
3. Another issue not related to this topic: In C++ is is better to use smart pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`) rather than raw pointers. Even better in your case is to use a `std::vector` to hold the values of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it I had to initialize the array with values at first, that's why it couldn't increment them:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        p[i] = 0;
    }
```

and then can modify the values. Trivial problem, trivial solution.

Comment: `new double[SIZE]{};` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

When you allocate a dynamic array, it is initially populated with whatever "garbage" is in memory at that point in time. For example, In the `p[id - 1] += time` scenario, the first time you access that index, you are adding `time` to whatever garbage value is already in there, resulting in the strange result. To avoid this, you can initialize the array with default values via value initialization. This should set all elements of the array to zero.

`double* p = new double[SIZE]();`